# WebStorm and .htaccess file

Tags: intellij-idea, frontend, webstorm

I wrote a simply .htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.google.com
```

Put it in the resource root and even in the project root, but it doesn't work.

When I request a wrong url, I see the default WebStorm 404 page.

How to get .htaccess to work?

Comment: .htaccess is used by the Apache http server. WebStorm doesn't care about it.

Comment: @JBNizet Well ... WebStorm's built-in web server can actually use .htaccess .. but only few instructions and `Error Document` is not one of them.

Comment: LazyOne, so, have I install and use Apache http server? Where can I read supported instructions of built-in web server?

Comment: I don't think that there is such list (but devs have mentioned this few times in their comments in related tickets/forum threads). If you need .htaccess then use Apache -- either valina (original) or as part of some package (e.g. WAMP/XAMPP/MAMP/etc) -- as it will be more close to production than any substitute.

Comment: For example (one of the mentions) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207037715-How-to-enable-htaccess-support-for-phpstorms-builtin-webserver